# ReactJS: Why does my textarea value always render invisible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to set up something simple.

Parent: `app.js`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //This acts as our global state
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      bio: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        username: "jonny",
        email: "jonny@mail.com",
        bio: "My bio...."
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
  handleFormChange = data => {
    this.setState(data);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Form data={this.state} onHandleFormChange={this.handleFormChange} />
        <p>Name from App state: {this.state.username}</p>
        <p>Email from App state: {this.state.email}</p>
        <p>Bio from App state: {this.state.bio}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child: `form.js`

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...this.props.data
    };
  }
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.props.onHandleFormChange({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  // static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  //   console.log(nextProps.data)
  //   return {
  //     ...nextProps.data
  //   };
  // }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.setState({ ...this.props.data });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            defaultValue={this.state.username}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            defaultValue={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <textarea
            name="bio"
            defaultValue={this.state.bio}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I created an artificial API call by using a `setTimeout()` in this example and I'm trying to set the state of the parent with the result of the API call. Then I wish to pass that as a prop to the child...

It's working except in the case of a `textarea`. I can see it if I inspect the DOM but it doesn't actually show in the browser...

Note the "my bio..." in the inspector, but the textarea being empty in the browser.

[image]

I've tried `componentWillUpdate()`, `componentDidUpdate()` and `getDerivedStateFromProps()` but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Note: I am not using `value=""` because then it stops me typing and this form is supposed to allow you to update existing values

Sandbox...   https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cloud-b5qkp?fontsize=14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work fine by using the `value` attribute instead of `defaultValue`. The `defaultValue` attribute should really only be used sparingly, since you almost always want your inputs to connect to component state. The optimal way to create a controlled input is by using `value`.

```
      <textarea
        name="bio"
        value={this.state.bio}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
```

Comment: You probably meant `value` attribute rather than value `attribute` :)

Comment: Oh man, I was using prop as the value before, so when I used `value` it didn't work, but forgot to try it again after changing it to use state.

Comment: @AshleyBrown it happens! Here's a fork of your sandbox with the working code :) https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-cherry-fhqjt

Answer (score 0):

Change the defaultValue in textarea to value